# Very Weird PHP Echo Error

Tags: php, echo, netflix

I am trying to echo out a URL that is generated via the Netflix API. The URL is held in the variable $movieid and when 'echo $movieid;' is typed it works. I need to get the value out of the PHP and into the JavaScript that Netflix provides and that's where I get the issue.

Let's say I have titleID = 7474747  . When I type the following code:

```
$movieid = "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/movie/".$titleID;
echo $movieid;
```

I get the following output:

```
[http]://api.netflix.com/catalog/movie/7474747
```

But when using the following code:

```
<div id="myMovieLocation">
  <?php echo "<img src=\"$img\" />"; ?>
  <script src="[http]://jsapi.netflix.com/us/api/js/api.js">
  {
   "title_id" : "<?php print $movieid; ?>",
   "button_type" : ["PLAY_BUTTON", "ADD_BUTTON"],
   "show_logo" : "true",
   "x" : "40",
   "y" : "20",
   "dom_id" : "myMovieLocation",
   "application_id" : "<?php echo $apiKey; ?>"
   }
   </script>
```

I do not get the same output for $movieid. A quick look at the source always shows the original URL with no number appended like this :

```
"title_id" : "[http]://api.netflix.com/catalog/movie/",
```

Everything else works out great, except that. I have tried echo, print, different variable names and nothing seems to work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As an addition, I tried "title_id" : "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/movie/<?php echo $titleID; ?>" and this still failed to append the numbers.

Comment: Why is your script source in `[http]` brackets? Or is there something I don't know? Have you tried it without the brackets around the `http`?

Comment: I couldn't have more than 2 links in a file and that seemed to stop the complaint. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: Then, I take it you tried it without the brackets then(?)

Comment: Yes, the brackets were added only on this website.

Comment: All I know is that somewhere between `$movieid = "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/movie/".$titleID;` and `"title_id" : "<?php print $movieid; ?>",` your `$movieid` value is being changed, because PHP won't magically cut off the numbers. Check your code between those two lines

Comment: After that block of HTML/JavaScript I reopened PHP to echo $movieid and the same, non truncated value is returned.

Comment: Try to change the concatenation from `$movieid = "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/movie/".$titleID;` to `$movieid = "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/movie/" . $titleID;` maybe the absence of the spaces might be the problem. There's usually spaces in concatenates.

Comment: yep @Fred i think so.

Comment: @Ash see my suggestion above.

Comment: @Ash look at answer using json_encode with PHP.

Comment: Spaces were added, Fred. They still give the same result. This is by far the weirdest thing I've encountered.

Comment: @Ash I'm picking at straws. What if you tried `$movieid = "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/movie/$titleID";` < minus concatenate or `$movieid = http://api.netflix.com/catalog/movie/$titleID;` < minus the quotes?

Comment: Are you sure your `$titleID` is declared before that javascript block?

Comment: @kidonchu that's what I was asking myself as well.

Comment: Sorry about the late replies. I gave up last night. The $titleID is defined before and is generated using a preg_replace. I can echo out the titleID before trying to append and I see it. Echoing out movieid shows the entire formed URL. Upon exiting PHP though it just vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

Just change with own code, `str_replace("[http]", "http://", $movie_id);`.

What are you get if you put `var_dump($movie_id);`? Share result....

Try this:

`"title_id" : \"<?php print $movieid; ?>\",`

If you receive `NULL` or nothing it's some wrong with returning result on variable `$movie_id`?

Try to convert to string, i think you receive INT so it can't parse example:

`echo (string) $movie_id;`

Or use `strval()` to make sure that you are integer converted to string:

`echo strval($movie_id);`

Due to errors: `Output from "title_id" : \"<?php print $movieid; ?>\" is: "title_id" : \"api.netflix.com/catalog/movie\",`

put into PHP code `"`:

```
"title_id" : <?php print 'http://"'.$movieid.'"/'.$title_id; ?>,
```

Or in another way, parse using PHP `json_encode`:

```
<div id="myMovieLocation">
  <?php echo "<img src=\"$img\" />"; ?>
  <script src="[http]://jsapi.netflix.com/us/api/js/api.js">
  {
    <?php

    $movie_id_result = (string)$movieid;

    $a = array
    ("title_id" => "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/movie/".$movie_id_result,
     "button_type" => "[\"PLAY_BUTTON\", \"ADD_BUTTON\"]",
     "show_logo" => "true",
     "x" => "40",
     "y" => "20",
     "dom_id" => "myMovieLocation",
     "application_id" => $apiKey
    );

    echo json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    ?>
  }
  </script>
```

And be notice when returning PHP result:

`titleID = 7474747` where `7474747` can be integer (INT). When you convert to JSON, make sure that is string using `strval()` or simple add `(string)` in before variable. Integer as result can confusing to json parser.

**Neflix API for PHP**

If this isn't yet solved, use PHP API for netflix from [source](http://developer.netflix.com/page/resources/sample_php) as sample PHP.

Comment: var_dump returns a space character
echo returns the URL

Comment: `var_dump($movie_id)` returns `NULL/(nothing)` so you not returning a result.

Comment: Output from "title_id" : \"<?php print $movieid; ?>\" is:  

"title_id" : \"http://api.netflix.com/catalog/movie/\",

Comment: so, you are not receiving ID and not http: is added.

Comment: or is parser confused (javascript is confused due to `"` string)

Comment: I tried the above with json_encode, Marin and I'm still getting that same output. This is what came out: {"title_id":"http:\/\/api.netflix.com\/catalog\/movie\/","button_type":"[\"PLAY_....

Comment: updated an answer, just added `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` to trim this slashes. So you are not receiving via `$movieid` nothing? Is this variable correct?

Comment: Maybe instead `$moviewid` go `$titleID`? And or add `(string)$titleID;`

Comment: Hello, are you solving this issue?